# Eclipse 2020-06 configuration error preventing launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I've downloaded Eclipse 2020-06 and installed JDK 14.0.2 and JRE 1.8.0_261 on a newly built laptop without any pre-existing versions of these applications. When I launch Eclipse, I receive the following error:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-jar C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.16.0.20200615-1200\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1200.v20200508-1552\eclipse_11000.dll
-startup C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 33a4_128
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-jar C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
```

The double-backslash followed by a forward slash in paths such as `C:\Users\my-username\eclipse\\plugins/...` leads me to suspect that there's an error with these paths in the config file, but I can't find this pattern anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a 32 bit Java - you need a 64 bit Java.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 - I naively assumed that the online installer would select an appropriate version. I've installed the 64-bit JRE and it launches as expected.